# Layout shows unexpected border around floated elements

Tags: css, layout, css-float, positioning

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/cZH7F/1/

Why does `.sample-section`'s border affect this large area that includes floated elements enclosed in a previous element?

**Edit (Solution):**

So, for future visitors, i will summarize what i learned here today

**White spaces in your `HTML` can elements cause to behave unexpected:**

- [With whitespaces](http://jsfiddle.net/mXUUp/2/)
- [Without them](http://jsfiddle.net/mXUUp/3/)

**CSS property `display: inline-block` can be an alternative for `float`**

- [inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/mXUUp/3/)
- [Float (works with whitespaces, for some reason)](http://jsfiddle.net/mXUUp/4/)

Comment: The CSS in your fiddle has some syntax errors in it, you seem to have nested styles within each other.  We should fix that first.

Comment: @MarcAudet

I am not sure if i understand you. Maybe you mean the scss syntax? :x

Comment: I don't use scss (yet) so I probably misunderstood the syntax.  However, the fiddle probably would not understand scss.  My apologies, no offense intended.  I did adjust the CSS and it gave the same results, so that was never an issue.  However, I did post a fix for you.

Comment: I did not feel offended :)

Actually, you can choose scss as your language of choice in jsfiddle's "Languages" options on the left.
Much thanks for your efforts, it is now much clearer

Comment: You actually got three good answers here, so it might be worth while to update your question since you touched on a very common problem that arises with using floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `display: inline-block;` to `.features-section` instead of `float:left`

```
.features-section{
   display: inline-block; /* remove float: left */
   --------
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would be very thankful if you could explain to me why this works

Comment: @Sprottenwels This just add height instead of floating elements as Chowlett explained.

Comment: If I were using `display: inline-block`, I would also apply it to `.first-section` because the content of `.first-section` could be longer than that of `.features-section`.  @Mr_Green is proposing a solution that does not use floats, probably the better choice in this application since it appears that you are creating a two column format.

Comment: @MarcAudet
I tried this, and removed every float, instead gave inline-block to both of the upper containers. I have to say that the second ones aligns below the first one:
http://jsfiddle.net/mXUUp/

Comment: Of course it does, because you have some white space between the two sections (a couple of CR) and the white space adds a 1ex with to the line with makes the line length greater than 100%.  If the sections had no white space, it would look okay, http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/mXUUp/1/

Comment: Personally, I would have made the inline-boxes 49% in width to avoid this issue.  Depends on how critical 50% is.

Comment: You can also use `vertical-align` if you need the boxes to align to the top of the parent container.

Comment: This is more and more confusing. I was convicted that if i am using box-sizing: border-box (which is applied on the actual site, not in the fiddle, yup), this would prevent such an issue. Thanks again

Comment: box-sizing is good but not yet supported by all browsers, however you can use vendor specific prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `.sample_section` starts at the same height as `.start_page_upper`, because that `div` has no height, because all its elements are `float`ing.

Add `clear: both;` to `.sample_section` to fix it.

Comment: This also works.  However, it is critical that `.sample_section` is always present in the layout.  For example, if your layout were part of a CMS with configurable widgets (think WordPress), then the section with the clear property might be optional and you would be better off using the `overflow: auto` property.  However, this comment is beyond the scope of the original question but worth keeping in mind should be the next big WordPress clone.

Answer (score 1):

The visual problem arises because of the floated elements generating a large clearance.

You can fix it by using the following rule:

```
.start-page-upper{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

It is illustrative to add outlines to the various sections so see how the layout is formatted, see: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cZH7F/3/

**Why Did the Floats Cause This?**

As pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192105/564353 the `.start_page_upper`'s height collapses to zero since its child elements are floated and hence out-of-flow (thus not contributing to the height of the containing block).  The following inflow element is `.sample_section` and that starts right after the zero-height `.start_page_upper`, so the top of the page.

However, the browser must provide space for the floated elements (known as clearance) and since the floated elements fill up the page width, they force the content within `.sample-section` to start a new line below the floats.

As a result, the border encloses the intrinsic height of the content and the height clearance height generated by the floated elements.

The `overflow: auto` triggers a different mode of formatting that takes care of the problem. (Without rereading the w3.org docs, I think that `overflow: auto` means to account for the overflowing content's height when computing the height of the containing block, and the floated content is overflowing.)